# image gallery rows grid javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, gallery

I'm trying to create javascript image gallery for multiple projects using loops (getting data from xml). A minimum of 3 images per project, arranged in rows of two.

I have crated the html for 4 images that looks correct (below), but i'm having difficulties translating this into something flexible.

```
<div class="project">
<div class="projectImage" id="projectImage" style="float: left;"><img src="image1.png"></div>
<div class="projectImage" id="projectImage" style="float: left; padding-left: 20px;"><img src="image2.png"></div>
```

I'm getting confused. Will i need loops inside loops to deal with the blocks of code that only need to be produced once, also how can i loop through 4+ items and place the image names grouped in twos like above?

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better to set margin-right.

```
<style>
.project {
    width: 200px;
}
.projectImage {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
</style>
...
<body>
<div class="project">
<div class="projectImage" id="img1"><img src="image1.png"></div>
<div class="projectImage" id="img2"><img src="image2.png"></div>
<div class="projectImage" id="img3"><img src="image3.png"></div>
<div class="projectImage" id="img4"><img src="image4.png"></div>
<div class="projectImage" id="img5"><img src="image5.png"></div>
```

Depending on .project's width, it'll be flexible.

http://jsfiddle.net/bzykh/ (Bunch of Google logo with 700 width of container)

http://jsfiddle.net/bzykh/1/ (Bunch of Google logo with 400 width of container)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest seperating your concerns to solve this problem in an understandable and flexible way.

- Let your data define the organisation of projects and images
- Let a templating engine ([Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)) convert your data to markup
- Let CSS handle wrapping your images into rows and other positional styling

**[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/YMFCA/)**

**Template:**

```
<script id="gallery-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each projects}}
    <div class="project">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <ul>
            {{#each images}}
            <li><img src="{{this}}"></li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var gallery = {
    projects: [
        {
            title: 'Gallery 1',
            images: ['http://placekitten.com/100/100', 'http://placekitten.com/100/100', 'http://placekitten.com/100/100', 'http://placekitten.com/100/100']
        },
        {
            title: 'Gallery 2',
            images: ['http://placekitten.com/100/100']
        }
    ]
};

var source   = $("#gallery-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var html     = template(gallery);

$(document.body).html(html);
```

**CSS:**

```
.project ul { overflow: hidden; }
.project ul li { float: left; }
/* break into rows of 2 */
.project ul li:nth-child(odd) { clear: both; }
```

*Edit: I realise this answer may be contributing too much, but you did ask it on the javascript tag, not css :)*

Comment: This looks very comprehensive! Thank you! I've come from Flash/AS2 where I made it all up as I went along. js,php & css are different enough to keep my poor designer head confused. This looks like I can go forward with the project now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look into the masonry jquery plugin or the wookmark jquery plugin when you want a really flexible grid design. First off this are quite new and interesting jquery extension and 2nd they also implements a 1d bin-packing algorithm so they stacks boxes in columns with maximum boxes per column goal. And that is automatic. At first it may be hard to learn and overkill to use but when you are familiar with it it can make grid layout very easy.

Comment: I'll take a look at this, maybe some hard work now will save me time in the future, I'm sure i'll have to make one of these again, thanks for the pointers.